# Geom_bar removed rows containing missing values, but doesn't?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

So here is the data frame I'm wanting to graph:

```
choc.BeanMainContinent   average
Africa                    3.16
Asia                      3.16
North America             3.20
Not Disclosed             2.95
Oceania                   3.24
South America             3.19
```

lowest value is 2.95, highest is 3.24 and there are no NAs.

```
ggplot(aveBeanSourceCont, aes(x = choc.BeanMainContinent, y = average)) + geom_bar(stat = "Identity") + ylim(2.90, 3.30)
```

But I'm still getting the "Removed 6 rows containing missing values (geom_bar)" error. Everything falls between the 2.90-3.30 range (and I get this error even when I expand that range), and there are no NA values. From my understanding, those would be the two causes for this error, but neither are present here. What else might cause this error?

[image]

Comment: btw -  one can also use `geom_col()`, which is identical to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, a a bar chart always starts at 0. This means, setting the limit different than zero makes it an "impossible value".

That is also the reason, why you may want to consider a different visualisation, i.e., something more appropriate for a continuous variable. e.g., a boxplot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)
foo <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], y = sample(6))

ggplot(foo, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  ylim(0.5, 6.5)
#> Warning: Removed 6 rows containing missing values (geom_col).

ggplot(foo, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  ylim(0, 6.5)
```

[image]

If you want to set the y limits to "focus" on specific plot areas, use `coord` instead:

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_col() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.5,6))
```